# How to deal with "Java Heap Space" error while running rjava

Tags: java, r, rjava, r-xlsx

I am using rJava package in R on MacOS. This error happened:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I need rJava to open an Excel file with xlsx package. With this error I can not read the .xlsx files. I wonder how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the java parameters with the following function at the start of your script.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")
```

You may also need restart your environment first.